# Codeigniter calendar multiple events on same day

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to add multiple events to codeigniter calendar. I have found solution for that already. The problem I am facing is that, for multiple events on same day I want array like this

```
$data = array(
        1 => 'class1',
        3 => array('class2', 'class3'),
        4 => 'class4'
    );
```

Here is my model function and mysql query

```
public function getClasses($year,$month)
{
    $this->db->like('date_from', $year."-".$month, 'after');
    $query = $this->db->get('classes');
    $data = array();
    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $data[(int)substr($row->date_from, 8, 2)] = $row->class_name; 
    }

    return $data;
}
```

`date_from` is in this format `2015-02-25`

Right now the function make single array for example

```
$events = array(
        1 => 'class1',
        4 => 'class4'
    );
```

But I want it to make nested array. How this can be solved?